# Tar excluding all files instead of just hidden folders

Tags: tar

I am trying to tar everything within my home folder into a tar and I want to exclude certain folders like hidden ones and test_tree (which is actually nested quite a bit inside of other folders).

I tried executing this command:

```
tar -vcf everything.tar . --exclude='.*' --exclude='test_tree'
```

inside of the home directory `cd ~` but the tar created was completely empty. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issues, --exclude='.*' works fine on MacOS but not on Linux.
You can do,

> tar -vcf everything.tar . --exclude='./.*' --exclude='test_tree'

Or

> tar -vcf everything.tar . --exclude='.[^/]*' --exclude='test_tree'

Answer (score 0):

It is the use of `.` as your source coupled with telling tar to exclude things starting with `.` that is the problem.  Try using the absolute path for example `/home/user` or `"$PWD"` if you are in the directory already and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to cobble up a file with the offending names, and go:

> tar cf my-precious.tar -X file-of-offenders .

(Dunno if -X is a GNUism, though... but you seem to be using GNU tar anyway).

Answer (score 0):

To match ["hidden files"](https://web.archive.org/web/20170903224737/https://plus.google.com/101960720994009339267/posts/R58WgWwN9jp) using a shell-style pattern, use `.[^.]*`.

Using `.*` matches the special directory entry `.` (and also `..`).  This is usually not what you want.